# How do I configure ipv6 on a LXC configured bridge?

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, lxc

I am trying to figure out how I can add IPv6 to lxcbr0 that LXC creates. The IPv4 could be configured in `/etc/default/lxc-net` but I find nothing about IPv6. Can this be done? I am running Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 1):

If you have a router advertisement daemon on your network, ipv6 will work automatically in your LXC container.  With bridged networking, your container will show up as just another Ethernet system, with its own MAC address, and be able to get an ipv6 address from the network.  If you don't have radvd, you could also manually add an ipv6 address inside the container with for instance, `ip addr add 2001:DB8::1234 dev eth0` or by editing (inside the container) /etc/network/interfaces.  Note that depending on how your network is configured, the ipv6 address may be based on your MAC address.  If you want the IPv6 address address to not change, you should specify the MAC in the lxc config like so:

```
# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 02:FF:AA:00:00:01
```